# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named requests in JENKINS

Tags: python, jenkins, import, module

Getting below error in Jenkins, while running a Python script

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named requests**

But when running from the command prompt using ""python <script.py>" and when running from VSCode directly no issue error related to import.

Please suggest any configuration required at Jenkins.

ThankYou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python package `requests` not installed on the Jenkins slave where your job run.

Try

```
pip install requests
python <script.py>
```

Comment: In my case, I have the package installed on the node—the Python script runs successfully, if I execute it locally. However, executing it from a Jenkins job's script results in ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: Maybe you login node with one user and Install the package to user home directpry and run Python script successfully.  But Jenkins job run on the node with another user,  under this user the package is not install.  Can you check which user is used by Jenkins job.

Comment: Something like this. In my case, I had two Python versions installed, and users defaulted to different versions. `path/to/correct/python -m pip install requests` fixed the problem.